# How much is 93 more than 47?

Tags: arithmetic

This was a question that i came across in my 7 year old daughters book. My wife and i have argued at length whether the two numbers should be added and subtracted.

I think the statement is ambiguous and both 140 and 46 can be the correct answers.

Below is the screenshot of a similar question in the book.

[image]

Comment: I would assume that they are asking for $96+47$, but I agree that the way you phrased it is unclear.

Comment: Yes, not a very clear question. You could also say that it is about twice as much. Or 104% more.

Comment: @lulu And personally I would gave guessed they were asking for 96-47. That just shows the ambiguity of this question :P

Comment: @Bram28 This was also my guess and it is the most natural interpretation of this exercise.

Comment: @Bram28  But bear in mind that we don't have the actual phrasing of the question, along with any context.  If nothing else:  For a $7$ year old's workbook, there really ought to be worked examples to go along with the questions.

Comment: Theres no context, its just this statement and then a box to fill the answer is there.

Comment: Do you have a link to the workbook?

Comment: Should stress: it is by no means unusual or surprising to find a poorly phrased question in a school book, sadly.  I'm just thinking that if we had the workbook we might be able to reverse engineer the question they intended.

Comment: I dont have a link to the online version. Have attached a photo though

Comment: I now agree that it can also be meant as the sum. Really terribly formulated. By the way, now we have $93$ instead of $96$.

Comment: The photo does not supply context.  As I said, for young students one really, really ought to include worked examples in with the homework.  Perhaps there are similar, but worked, questions elsewhere?  Again:  maybe it's just a poorly phrased problem.  If so, there's not much to be done beyond pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: Yep. The actual numbers were different. Didn't remember them while typing out the question. Nevertheless, the statement is still the same

Comment: Have you looked at how addition and subtraction are taught in her book? I would be shocked if the first time that phrasing was used was in the problem set.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Yes, that's my point.  With young students, one ought to take exceptional care with phrasing. There really should be prior instances of this formulation.

Comment: @lulu But he has the book. It should be clear. To me, $93$ more than $47$ is $140$. For subtraction, it should be worded as "how much more is $93$ than $47$?". Either way, the book should clear this up.

Comment: If my child understood how to solve an unambiguous question in general, I would be happy enough and call it a day. If it was for a school assignment, I would suggest clearly stating  what her assumption is and answer accordingly.

Comment: Clearly the only correct answer is to track down the book author and send them an angry letter.

Comment: It could make a fun starter question for a class to discuss as they came to realised the ambiguity...

Comment: If you can't search the book for similar formulations, then I suggest bringing the matter to the instructor's attention.  And (possibly) seeking a better written workbook.

Comment: Awfully phrased question. Are there any other places in the book where the authors possibly use the same terminology, but in an already-solved problem? If yes, what *do* they mean? (Addition or subtraction?) "Ask the instructor" may be a choice, but there are instructors who have the secret "answer book" in which they will have read that the "right" answer here is $140$ (or $46$?!) - and for those people the argument is over. Hope this one is more reasonable than that.

Comment: The principle problem of text exercises : Much care is needed to formulate them clearly. It is well possible that the author of the book did not notice this ambiguity , to be honest , I might have overlooked it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is not my native language, but I think that a better match would be

- How much is $93$ more than $47$ ? Answer: $140$.
- By how much is $93$ more than $47$ ? Answer: $46$.

This said, the phrasing is indeed quite *dangerous*.

Comment: The second should be "How much more is 93 than 47?". There is no ambiguity in this problem. First graders are taught to add by placing their finger on the zero of the number line and counting forward by the first number and then further by the second number. It is perfectly natural to say $3 + 5$ is obtained by counting to the right by three and then five more. I really doubt that a professional editor would allow "How much is 93 more than 47?" to mean subtraction.

Comment: @JohnDouma "There is no ambiguity in this problem": if there wasn't, this post would not exist.

Comment: The post exists because a non-native speaker thinks that "How much is 93 more than 47" could mean subtraction. That is no more valid than the statement "I am having twenty dollars".

Comment: @JohnDouma: who told you that the OP is non-native ?

Comment: You are correct. That was a poor assumption on my part. He could be someone who just doesn't understand English that well.